# Detecting end of scrolling using a ScrollViewer control in Silverlight with WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, scrollviewer

I've got a page with a ScrollViewer control. I'm trying to implement an endless-scrolling method which lazy loads content from a webservice when the user has scrolled down to the end of the content.

This seemed like a trivial task, but the most obivious event to handle (ManipulationCompleted) does not work correctly for my requirements. The event seems to fire when the user stops touching the screen. But usually the scrollviewer keeps scrolling after that, because it uses kinetic scrolling. As a result, I can't accurately detect when the scrollviewer has reached the end of the content.

A solution to this problem is described on [an MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/30/windows-phone-mango-change-listbox-how-to-detect-compression-end-of-scroll-states.aspx). This however does not work for my situation. The article describes the usage of a ListBox with an embedded ScrollViewer. But I'm not using a ListBox, I use a ScrollViewer with some other controls inside.

When I try to use the code from the blog, this code fails:

```
ScrollViewer sv = this.myScrollViewer;
FrameworkElement element = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sv, 0) as FrameworkElement;
```

with this Exception:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled Message=Specified
>   argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name:
>   childIndex

I believe I did every step the blog suggested, and also added the suggested Style element to my App.xaml

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ScrollViewer != null)
{
  if ((ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight != 0 && ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset != 0 &&
  ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight - ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset) <= 10) || ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight == 0)
  {
    //do work here
  }    
}
```

I hope this helps